# React : Cannot read property 'object' of undefined at Object.defineProperty.value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I've been playing around with React lately, ran into this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined
>       at Object.defineProperty.value (app.js:33843)
>       at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>       at Object.defineProperty.value (app.js:33752)
>       at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>       at Object. (app.js:5250)
>       at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>       at app.js:63
>       at app.js:66

I've noticed this has something to do with propTypes, in all of the components which have them. If I delete propTypes block from one component, the other one gets a similiar error.

```
Base.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

My package.json :

```
{
"name": "mernapp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "test app",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon --use_strict index.js",
    "bundle": "webpack"
},
"author": "Gytis Gecevicius",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "material-ui": "^0.19.4",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "validator": "^9.1.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.1",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
}
```

}

Comment: What is your question? Is the error not clear?

Comment: After trying to remove PropTypes from Base and other components, noticed that PropTypes is always undefined. What could be the issue?

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate linked at the top of your question.